# How to add product variations for large number of products in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I have a Wordpress site with WooCommerce selling photo prints. Currently there are around 150 photos. I managed to import the photos as products fine, but each print has 3 sizes.

I've added a Size attribute with 3 "terms" for the variations. But adding these to the products one by one will take forever. There must be a quicker way!

I've tried exporting all the products and adding the variations in the CSV (copying the variations I added for the first few products and changing all relevant IDs/SKUs), but reimporting doesn't do anything - no variations are added for other products.

I've even tried diff-ing the database before and after adding variations manually, and thought I'd figured out exactly what I needed to add... but adding posts and postmetas to the database still doesn't add the variations! Surely there is an easier way?!

Comment: Your export idea should have worked.  When I need to do a large import I normally setup a test site with 1 product (or 1 product for each type), then add all my fields or variations needed.  Do my export so I can see an example of the table structure and edit my import file accordingly.  Keep in mind you may need to map the columns to the correct fields when doing the import.

Comment: Use wp all import..saves life and time..